# Add label to checkbox in nested form writing to an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, form-for

I'm trying to add a user's name next to the checkbox associated with their id. My eventual goal is to use the custom attribute writer, users_attributes=, to assign the id to a column in my ListsUsers table called "admin_id".  I can't seem to figure out how to access the user's name in the form to create the label.

FYI, for the purposes of this exercise I am avoiding using "accepts_nested_attributes_for" in the List.rb

My Form:

```
<%= form_for(@list) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :users do |users_fields| %>
    <%= users_fields.label :name %>
    <%= users_fields.check_box :id %>
  <% end %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My strong params in ListsController.rb

```
def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name, :list_type, invites_attributes: [:email, :status], users_attributes: [:id, :name])
end
```

My customer attribute writer in List.rb

```
def users_attributes=(users_attributes)
    binding.pry
end
```

I'm able to grab the attributes at the pry.  Just need to label the boxes so the User knows what they are checking.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
<%= form_for(@list) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :users do |users_fields| %>
    <%= users_fields.object.name %>
      <%= users_fields.check_box :id, checked: true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```